# Optimising compatibility-conflict graph solution - python recursive routine

Tags: python, performance, recursion, numpy

#### Background

I'm implementing an algorithm which localises overlapping sound sources using the time-difference-of-arrivals across 3 sensors [1]. Compatible 'triples' (e.g. with only 2 common sensors) need to be joined up to make larger *N* sensor graphs. The compatible triples are found using a recursive routine (```combine_all``) until no new solutions are found.

The routine runs well when there are small # of triples, but I've empirically observed for every 10X increase in triple number, there's a ~10^5.5 increase in run-time (using linear regression) - which is problematic (meaning up to 12 hours of run-time on my actual data).

###### Reference

[1] Kreissig & Yang 2013, Fast and reliable TDOA assignment in multi-source reverberant environments, ICASSP 2013 [paper link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6637668/?casa_token=3oKOQUJRuWQAAAAA:JNbwI-gf0m0ozfAKbAQJzblq8qE-NPTJ49hgJILMxG_2ZM9MJOt4PQOvPEQn9TXJZSzD_ON6YA).

#### Code and initial profiling

The `combine_all` routine accepts the compatibility-conflict matrix describing the compatibility/conflict of all triple pairs. From the currently available triples - their in/compatibility to the current solution are checked and kept or eliminated.  The compatible nodes are checked by `get_Nvl`, and incompatible nodes are checked by `get_not_Nvl`.

Initial profiling with iPython `%lprun` told me the `get_Nvl` and `get_not_Nvl` is where ~80% (40% and 40% each) is spent in `combine_all` - and I've tried my best to optimise the current code with no luck.

````
import numpy as np 
from itertools import chain, product


def combine_all(Acc, V, l, X):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    Acc : (N_triples,N_triples) np.array
        The compatibility-conflict graph. Value of 1 means compatible node pair, -1 is incompatible, 0 is undefined.
    V_t : set
        V_tilda. The currently considered vertices (a sub-set of V, all vertices)
    l : set
        The solution consisting of the currently compatible vertices.      
    
    Returns
    -------
    solutions_l : list with sublists
        A somewhat messy output - must be run through ```format_combineall``` to get
        nice output.

    '''
    # determine N_v(l) and !N_v(l)
    # !N_v(l) are the vertices incompatible with the current solution
    N_vl = get_Nvl(Acc, V, l)
    N_not_vl = get_NOT_Nvl(Acc, V, l)

    solutions_l = []
    if len(N_vl) == 0:
        solutions_l.append(l)

    else:
        # remove conflicting neighbour
        V = V.difference(N_not_vl)
        # unvisited compatible neighbours
        Nvl_wo_X = N_vl.difference(X)
        for n in Nvl_wo_X:
            Vx = V.difference(set([n]))
            lx = l.union(set([n]))
            solution = combine_all(Acc, Vx, lx, X)
            if solution:
                solutions_l.append(solution)
            X = X.union(set([n]))
    return solutions_l


def get_Nvl(Acc, V_t, l):
    '''Checks for compatible vertices   
    
    Essentially, two for loops run across the
    available triples (v in V_t) and   the current solution set (u in l)
    - to access the ```Acc[v,u]``` entries. If all ```Acc[v,u]``` values
    are +1, then ```v``` is compatible with the current solution ```l```.
    If any of the ```Acc[v,u]``` values is -1  then that ```v``` is not compatible anymore.

    Returns
    -------
    Nvl : set
        Solution of vertices that are compatible to at least one other vertex
        and not in conflict with any of the other vertices.
    '''
    Nvl = []
    if len(l)>0:
        for v in V_t:
            for u in l:
                if Acc[v,u]==1:
                    Nvl.append(v)
                elif Acc[v,u]==-1:
                    if v in Nvl:
                        Nvl.pop(Nvl.index(v))
        return set(Nvl)
    else:
        return V_t

def get_Nvl_fast(Acc, V_t, l):
    '''See CombineAll for docs
    '''
    if len(l)>0:
        all_uv = np.array(np.meshgrid(V_t, l)).T.reshape(-1,2)
        def get_acc(X):
            return Acc[X[0], X[1]]
        Acc_values = np.apply_along_axis(get_acc, 1, all_uv)
        rows_w_min1 = np.where(Acc_values<0)
        v_vals_w_conflicts = np.unique(all_uv[rows_w_min1,0])
        Nvl = np.setdiff1d(V_t, v_vals_w_conflicts)
        return Nvl
    else:
        return V_t


def get_NOT_Nvl(Acc:np.array, V:set, l:set):
    N_not_vl = []
    if len(l)>0:
        for v in V:
            for u in l:
                if Acc[v,u]==-1:
                    N_not_vl.append(v)
                elif Acc[v,u]==1:
                    if v in N_not_vl:
                        N_not_vl.pop(N_not_vl.index(v))
    else:
        N_not_vl = []
    return set(N_not_vl)

# ---- not performance related section -- formats output into easily readable
# form
def format_combineall(output):
    semiflat = flatten_combine_all(output)
    only_sets = []
    for each in semiflat:
        if isinstance(each, list):
            for every in each:
                if isinstance(every, set):
                    only_sets.append(every)
        elif isinstance(each, set):
            only_sets.append(each)
    return only_sets

def flatten_combine_all(entry):
    if isinstance(entry, list):
        if len(entry)==1:
            return flatten_combine_all(entry[0])
        else:
            return list(map(flatten_combine_all, entry))
    elif isinstance(entry, set):
        return entry
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{entry} can only be set or list')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # compatibility-conflict graph from [1]
    A = np.array([[ 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [ 0, 1, 0,-1, 1, 0],
                  [ 0, 1,-1, 0,-1, 0],
                  [-1, 0, 1,-1, 0, 1],
                  [-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

    qq = combine_all(A, set(range(6)), set([]), set([]))
    neat_output = format_combineall(qq)
    # Expected answer: 
    # >>> print(neat_output)
    # >>> [{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5}]
````

#### No luck with optimisation experiments

Since the `get_Nvl` + `get_not_Nvl` is where most of the time spent - I've focussed on performing optimisations there. To begin with I worked only `get_Nvl` (both `Nvl` functions have very similar structure.
In the current `get_Nvl` implementation - there are two for loops, with `i,j` referencing values in the `Acc` compatibility-conflict matrix. I've tried multiple things that have lead to no improvement or even increase in runtime, of which here I report the two that I can now recollect.

1. Converting serial loop-in-loop (i,j) into a direct i,j `product` - that can be used to check the values of `Acc` in a `map` call.
2. converting the loop-in-loop into a numpy iterable form (np.apply_along_axis) (e.g. see `get_Nvl_fast`)
3. Converting the `if,else` flow into dictionary calls. (`e.g. action_to_take[Acc[v,u]]` instead of `if Acc[v,u]==-1:...`)

#### Solutions to speeding up the code?

I've run out of ideas on how to speed up the code in Python - and am now considering using a C++ implementation that I can call from Python (though my C++ is non-existent/rusty).

I'd be grateful for ideas on how to speed up my Python code before investing too deep into another language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style & Maintenance

Prior to optimisation fussiness,

Use PEP484 type hints.

Docstrings are typically in double quotes rather than single quotes.

Do a PEP8 pass with a linter or good IDE; they will point out e.g. that you need spaces around `==`.

You're so close to having a unit test! Write an `assert`.

### Performance

Some of this will make a difference and some won't. It's good that you're profiling; keep doing that.

You've missed some opportunities for early `return`; pursue this, for example when you `get_NOT_Nvl(Acc, V, l)`.

Rather than `V = V.difference`, just `V -=`.

Rather than `set([n])`, prefer `{n}`; but better yet don't do a set-to-set operation at all. Clone the set and then use `.discard` and `.add` as needed, since this is a single-element operation.

`get_Nvl` needs to operate on `Nvl` as a set instead of as a list cast to a set. I anticipate this helping, since `Nvl.pop()` and `Nvl.index()` are much more inefficient than a set `discard`. The same applies to `get_NOT_Nvl`.

More broadly, Python is bad at recursion. If you absolutely must have a recursive solution, as you fear: it is time to brush up on C++.

### Suggested

````
import numpy as np


def combine_all(Acc: np.ndarray, V: set[int], l: set[int], X: set[int]) -> list[set[int]]:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    Acc : (N_triples,N_triples) np.array
        The compatibility-conflict graph. Value of 1 means compatible node pair, -1 is incompatible, 0 is undefined.
    V_t : set
        V_tilda. The currently considered vertices (a sub-set of V, all vertices)
    l : set
        The solution consisting of the currently compatible vertices.

    Returns
    -------
    solutions_l : list with sublists
        A somewhat messy output - must be run through ```format_combineall``` to get
        nice output.

    """
    # determine N_v(l) and !N_v(l)
    # !N_v(l) are the vertices incompatible with the current solution
    N_vl = get_Nvl(Acc, V, l)
    if len(N_vl) == 0:
        return [l]

    solutions_l = []
    # remove conflicting neighbour
    V -= get_NOT_Nvl(Acc, V, l)
    # unvisited compatible neighbours
    N_vl -= X
    X = set(X)

    for n in N_vl:
        Vx = set(V)
        Vx.discard(n)
        lx = set(l)
        lx.add(n)
        solution = combine_all(Acc, Vx, lx, X)
        if solution:
            solutions_l.append(solution)
        X.add(n)
    return solutions_l


def get_Nvl(Acc: np.ndarray, V_t: set[int], l: set[int]) -> set[int]:
    """Checks for compatible vertices

    Essentially, two for loops run across the
    available triples (v in V_t) and   the current solution set (u in l)
    - to access the ```Acc[v,u]``` entries. If all ```Acc[v,u]``` values
    are +1, then ```v``` is compatible with the current solution ```l```.
    If any of the ```Acc[v,u]``` values is -1  then that ```v``` is not compatible anymore.

    Returns
    -------
    Nvl : set
        Solution of vertices that are compatible to at least one other vertex
        and not in conflict with any of the other vertices.
    """
    if len(l) < 1:
        return V_t

    Nvl = set()
    for v in V_t:
        for u in l:
            a = Acc[v, u]
            if a == 1:
                Nvl.add(v)
            elif a == -1:
                Nvl.discard(v)
    return Nvl


def get_NOT_Nvl(Acc: np.array, V: set[int], l: set[int]) -> set[int]:
    if len(l) < 1:
        return set()

    N_not_vl = set()
    for v in V:
        for u in l:
            if Acc[v, u] == -1:
                N_not_vl.add(v)
            elif Acc[v, u] == 1:
                N_not_vl.discard(v)
    return N_not_vl


def format_combineall(output: list) -> list[set[int]]:
    """formats output into easily readable
    form"""
    semiflat = flatten_combine_all(output)
    only_sets = []
    for each in semiflat:
        if isinstance(each, list):
            for every in each:
                if isinstance(every, set):
                    only_sets.append(every)
        elif isinstance(each, set):
            only_sets.append(each)
    return only_sets


def flatten_combine_all(entry: list) -> list:
    if isinstance(entry, list):
        if len(entry) == 1:
            return flatten_combine_all(entry[0])
        else:
            return list(map(flatten_combine_all, entry))
    if isinstance(entry, set):
        return entry
    raise TypeError(f'{entry} can only be set or list')


def test() -> None:
    # compatibility-conflict graph from [1]
    A = np.array([[ 0, 1, 0, 0,-1,-1],
                  [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [ 0, 1, 0,-1, 1, 0],
                  [ 0, 1,-1, 0,-1, 0],
                  [-1, 0, 1,-1, 0, 1],
                  [-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

    qq = combine_all(A, set(range(6)), set(), set())
    neat_output = format_combineall(qq)
    assert neat_output == [{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 5}]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
````

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! Set based formulation is much more elegant - however, as you predicted, sadly not much faster :|. Need to go down the Cpp path I guess..